# Proper way to use 3rd party .so files in android

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface

im stuck with this problem and dont know what im doing wrong. Please help me out.

Im working on an android project where I have to use 2 native library(.so) file. These 2 files are not generated by me, i just have to use them in my project.

I have placed these .so files under libs->armeabi folder. In the code i have used System.loadLibrary("name") inside a static block to load these library files. After doing this, i clean the project and run the application. I get the following error

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

What am i missing. I have unchecked the first two options in build settings as well.

Note: I am not developing the native library. I am just using it. It was being used in a previous version, so I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong in the way the .so files have been generated.

PS: My ultimate requirement is like this,
My android application will have a jar which I am developing. The methods in the jar will make use of these native functions. The main application will not directly access the native functions. Should i place the .so files in the jar or should it be in the main application. How should i package the jar and .so files.

Please help me out, this is my first time using native functions and im totally lost. Links to any materials would be great. ﻿

Comment: its very hard to help you without seeing some code on what youre trying to do. maybe provide some code of where your calling the methods in the .so file

Comment: Please clarify if you are using Eclipse or Android studio

Answer (score 2):

1. Set PATH to your NDK
   Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> set path to the NDK
2. Right click on an Android project and select Android Tools -> Add native support.
3. Make changes to your Android.mk file to include this .so file

   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   ```
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE := <module_name>

   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <.so file name>

   LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../jni/include   

   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

Clean project and build again